# DataGridViewComboBox dropdown size on multiline

Tags: winforms

I have a DataGridViewComboBox in a DataGrid. One of the other columns allows multiple lines of text to be entered.

My problem is that the dropdown in the DataGridViewComboBox expands to fill the cell. I would like the dropdown to only be one line.

Here is an examples: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1JC0.jpg. In this example, the first column's dropdowns should only be one line, and not fill the whole cell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cell style's alignment and display style:

```
var datagrid = new DataGridView();

var combobox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

combobox.DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopLeft};

combobox.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
```

MSDN on [DataGridViewContentAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx)

MSDN on [DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxdisplaystyle(v=vs.110).aspx)